# More combinations for Angular Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: angular, redirect, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, keydown

Im trying to create keyboard shortcuts for our website. One of which is trying to get the user to easily redirect to whatever page they want.
I manage to get basics working like simply having shift + r like below:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown.shift.r') spaceEvent() {
    this.redirect();
  }
```

However, I don't want any combinations to mess with what the user might already be doing, So I wanted to make it built on Shift + 2 letter keys. I can't get it to work though, whether I change it to:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown.shift.r.s') spaceEvent() {
    this.redirect();
  }
```

or even restructuring to:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event']) spaceEvent(event: any) {
    if ( event.key == "r" && event.key == "s" && event.key == "Shift") {
      this.redirect();
    };
  }
```

It's not working, is there something I'm missing? Are the Keys not written correctly?
Edit: If it's not possible, what other combinations can I do that won't interfere with the user? Combinations like TAB + "s" don't seem to work nor does Enter + "s".

Edit2: I tried making conditionals but it doesn't seem do have them be pressed together, you can just activate it in sequence which isn't really what I'm going for:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event']) spaceEvent(event: any) {
    if ( event.key == "Shift") {
      this.keySwitch1 = true;
    };

    if (this.keySwitch1 && event.key == "r") {
      this.keySwitch2 = true;
    };

    if (this.keySwitch2 && event.key == "s") {
      this.settingRedirect();
    }
  }
```

Edit3: Im sticking with Alt key combinations but I will leave this question open to see if there's better options for multiple key commands.

Comment: I believe you can only have one `event.key` at a time, so you would have to construct this such that a keydown of either r or s sets a flag and then check that the other key is flagged before a corresponding `keyup`. That's a lot of logic, so maybe there is already a library out there that does this sort of thing.

Comment: I tried setting up variables that turn true when the other buttons are pressed but that just causes the button combination right after another to redirect rather than at the same time.

Comment: I don't think you want `event.key == 'Shift'`, but rather, `event.shiftKey`.